# Installing in a vehicle with no ACC position

Tags: audio

I have a 2008 Ducato with no ACC position on the ignition. Can I still install a Pioneer SPH-230DAB?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can either connect it so it can come on permanently - and you have to remember to turn it off or you can connect it to an ignition supply, so it is only on when the ignition is on ie engine running.